# OpenVPN doesn't work on port 443 UDP in Azure

Tags: azure, port-forwarding, pfsense

I'm trying to setup pfSense on Azure and having mixed results. My endgoal is to provide OpenVPN connections on port 443 via UDP however I don't seem to able to get this working.

Symptoms:

- OpenVPN works on port 443 TCP
- OpenVPN doesn't work on port 443 UDP

I did some basic troubleshooting using the `nc command`.Running `nc -luv 443` on the pfSense and connecting using `nc -vu 10.0.20.5 443` from another Linux Azure VM works, however using the same command with the public IP of pfSense doesn't lead to successful connection. Even though `nc` says `Connection to <PF_SENSE_PUBLIC_IP> 443 port [udp/https] succeeded!` on the remote Linux VM, no data is transfered.

I'm almost certain that I configured the pfSense firewall correctly with this rule:

```
pass  in  quick  on $WAN reply-to ( hn0 10.0.20.1 ) inet proto { tcp udp }  from any to 10.0.20.5 port 443 tracker 1483705933 keep state  label "USER_RULE: OpenVPN"
```

I previously also had setup the Azure network security group to provide inbound access to UDP/TCP 443 but that didn't have any effect either - so right now I have removed the network security group alltogether without any obvious changes.

The webUI is accessible on port 8888, previously I tried 4433 but that didn't work - magically it worked on 8888 (even without configuring any Azure network security group).

In case you might think that this could be a client problem - I have tried with different Linux VMs both on Azure and hosted with other providers where I'm pretty certain that outgoing UDP 443 is not blocked!

Is Azure just broken or am I doing something wrong?

**Update:**
It appears the problem has vanished - at least on port 443. After not having touched the machines since I have written this post (4 days ago) - I tried it out once more and all of a sudden it works on port 443. However I now tried the `nc` test also with port 1194 (which is configured exactly the same as port 443) and still can't manage to get a connection on the public IP.

Comment: Can you confirm if this is a classic or ARM vNet? Also it's not clear, are you accessing this from vm's inside Azure on the same vNet, or from outside of Azure?

Comment: It is a new vNet (I guess it's ARM - but I'm new to a Azure... its in a resource group) and I'm able to access it using the local IP of the VM on other VMs on the same Azure Subnet, but I'm not able to access it using the public IP on any VM (neither on Azure, nor with other providers).

Comment: OK, do you have any NSG's in place currently? You mentioned you hadn't configured them, but does that mean there are none, or that they are but set to default? The reason I ask is if you have a default NSG setup it will allow traffic from the local vnet through, but will block external traffic, which is what you are seeing.

Comment: I had NSGs in place - also configured with the correct ports opened, but that didn't work. Googling for this problem many people suggested disassociating the NSG and then re-enabling them. So I tried that and it didn't work. So right now there are no NSGs, ports 22, 443 and 80 are still open but the rest ist still closed.